# Simplify toggle button change BackColor Code VBA

Tags: vba, excel

im new in VBA making, so all code below is still working tho but it takes a lot of line of codes. Even it is easier to maintain but if someone can simplify my noob-code to cut some lines and more eye-pleasing?

there are more than 20 toggle buttons in my userform

this is the example of my code, need help for make it simpler

```
Private Sub tgglC_Result1_Click()
If tgglC_Result1.Value = True Then
    tgglC_Result1.BackColor = &HFF00&
    tgglNC_Result1.Enabled = False
    lblResult1.Caption = Now
    lblResult1.Visible = True
Else
    tgglC_Result1.BackColor = &H8000000F
    tgglNC_Result1.Enabled = True
    lblResult1.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
Private Sub tgglC_Result2_Click()
If tgglC_Result2.Value = True Then
    tgglC_Result2.BackColor = &HFF00&
    tgglNC_Result2.Enabled = False
    lblResult2.Caption = Now
    lblResult2.Visible = True
Else
    tgglC_Result2.BackColor = &H8000000F
    tgglNC_Result2.Enabled = True
    lblResult2.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
Private Sub tgglC_Result3_Click()
If tgglC_Result3.Value = True Then
    tgglC_Result3.BackColor = &HFF00&
    tgglNC_Result3.Enabled = False
    lblResult3.Caption = Now
    lblResult3.Visible = True
Else
    tgglC_Result3.BackColor = &H8000000F
    tgglNC_Result3.Enabled = True
    lblResult3.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
Private Sub tgglC_Result4_Click()
If tgglC_Result4.Value = True Then
    tgglC_Result4.BackColor = &HFF00&
    tgglNC_Result4.Enabled = False
    lblResult4.Caption = Now
    lblResult4.Visible = True
Else
    tgglC_Result4.BackColor = &H8000000F
    tgglNC_Result4.Enabled = True
    lblResult4.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try [CODE REVIEW](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/71565/om3r)

Answer (score 0):

best way should be using a Class

but a more "conventional" way could help you reducing typing burden, too:

- define a unique toggle control handling sub

  ```
      Private Sub tgglC_Result_Click()
          Dim NC As Control

          With Me
              Set NC = .Controls(VBA.Replace(.ActiveControl.Name, "tgglC", "tgglNC")) '<--| set the "counter part" toggle button control of the "Active" control (i.e. the one being currently toggled)
              With .ActiveControl
                  .BackColor = IIf(.Value, &HFF00&, &H8000000F)
                  NC.Enabled = Not .Value
              End With
          End With
      End Sub
  ```
- call it from any of your event handler

  ```
  Private Sub tgglC_Result1_Click()
      tgglC_Result_Click
  End Sub

  Private Sub tgglC_Result2_Click()
      tgglC_Result_Click
  End Sub

  Private Sub tgglC_Result3_Click()
      tgglC_Result_Click
  End Sub

  ...
  ```

Comment: it didnt work for me tho, first click (value = true) the button turns to green but when the 2nd clicked (value = false) , it still on green. I dont understand how to edit the code

Comment: I had tested it and it worked with, as you wrote, those toggle buttons inside a userform. Do you have those buttons inside some other control (like a Frame)?

Comment: oh yes i forgot, it is inside MultiPage. What should i change?

Comment: the same code works if all those controls are in the _same_ container control like a `MultiPage`

Comment: all of it are in multipage.pages(1), how to edit the code?

Comment: As I said, the code works if all the toggle buttons are in the same _container_ control like a multipage page. Since you see toggle buttons turnin green the first time you click them but not turning back grey when you click them again, step through your code by placing a breakpoint at "With Me" statement to have your macro stop upon reaching it and then press F8 to step through each subsequent statement while using immediate window to query relevant variables values (like type "?ActiveControl.Name" and press return)

Answer (score 0):

Not really a simplifying solution, but this is what I used when I needed to supply logic to 60+ controls on an Access subform (similar task to yours):

```
Sub makeCode()
Dim i As Integer    
For i = 1 To 4
        Debug.Print "Private Sub tgglC_Result" & i & "_Click()"
        Debug.Print "tgglC_Result" & i & ".BackColor = &HFF00&"
        Debug.Print "tgglNC_Result2.Enabled = False"
        Debug.Print "lblResult" & i & ".Caption = Now"
        Debug.Print "lblResult" & i & ".Visible = True"
        Debug.Print "End Sub"
        Debug.Print ""
    Next
End Sub
```

Copy the result from the Immediate window into the code editor. It's easy to change all the subroutines, too: just change the loop body, run it, and replace old code.

Comment: i didnt get it how to use your code, should i make a private sub over your code? when i tried it didnt work

Comment: Yes, I modified my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Private sub tgglC_Result1_Click()
makecode
end sub , doesnt work. no color changing at all. am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, my answer had a mistake - it has to be a sub, not a private sub. Copy it now and run.

Comment: still, the color is not changing. i have no idea what happened

Comment: try replacing the &HFF00& with vbGreen, or RGB(0,210,0)